create an LWC to display hyperlinked Record Name
It is a fresh follow up of my previous post, since i have tried few things other that sfdcfox's suggestion on my previous post.
I basically need a very simple component. It should display the value of "Name" field on the record. And it should be hyperlinked to the URL of the record. This component can be placed on either Contract, or Order object pages (with possibility of using it o other objects as well ... so i am trying to avoid if else) ... this is the important part and this is what i am struggling with. In most examples i see people specify fields like Contract.Name or Order.Name, but i cant hardcode.
Back in good old days, we had an aura component that did this -
customEntityNameLookup.cmp
<aura:component implements="ui:visible,force:hasRecord" description="Makes the record accessible via the Name field as a lookup">
    <force:outputLookup label="{!v.record.Name}" value="{!v.record.Id}"/>
</aura:component>

and this sort and sweet component was enough (no controller, no helper). Now i need to replace that aura component with a LWC.
I am trying to do this -
customEntityNameLookup.js
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';

import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
export default class BusopEntityNameLookup extends LightningElement {
@api objectApiName
@api recordId;
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', layoutTypes: ["Full"]})
object;
get Name() {
    //somehow even Full Layout does not contain the field "Name" on order or Contract records. this.object.data shows all other fields, except "Name" 
    return getFieldValue(this.object.data, this.objectApiName + '.Name');
}

get RecordURL() {
    //somehow get the URL of the record dynamically
    return 'https://brave-hawk-obcyc7-dev-ed.trailblaze.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Order/801aj00000Oe59dAAB/view';
}

}
customEntityNameLookup.html
<template>
            <lightning-formatted-url value={RecordURL} label={Name}>
            </lightning-formatted-url>
</template>

customEntityNameLookup.js-meta.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>61.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>

but not sure how to write Name() and RecordURL() functions properly. Any help/suggestion would be appreciated. If there is a completely different and easier way to do this, let me know

Make sure to request the name field in the Get Record, using this.objectApiName + ".Name". The trick is to ensure you set the fields to retrieve after the objectApiName has been set, which means making the latter a get/set property and setting up the fields array (a private property on your component you use in the Get Records wire as a reactive parameter) in the set method. This is similar to this Q&A though doing it through the objectApiName property.

@PhilW - that, conceptually thats correct. In the wire adaptor, i added Layout as "full", and after that it retrieved all the fields, and your way of specifying the field dynamically would have worked.... only issue was that Name field wasnt retrieved even in full layout. I dont know why.

You can use the getRecord wire adapter to fetch the record data and then construct the URL dynamically based on the recordId.
HTML:
<template>
    <lightning-formatted-url value={recordPageUrl} label={name}></lightning-formatted-url>
</template>

JS:
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class UrlName extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName; // Include this line to accept the object API name dynamically
    recordPageUrl;

    // Use a getter to construct the fields array dynamically
    get fields() {
        return [`${this.objectApiName}.Name`];
    }

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: '$fields' })
    object;

    get name() {
        // Use the object API name to access the Name field value
        return this.object.data ? this.object.data.fields.Name.value : '';
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        // Generate a URL to the record page
        this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.recordId,
                actionName: 'view',
            },
        }).then(url => {
            this.recordPageUrl = url;
        });
    }
}

XML:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>57.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>

This will allow you to use the component on any object page without hardcoding the object name. The NavigationMixin is used to generate the URL dynamically based on the recordId, and the getRecord wire adapter is used to retrieve the record data.
Output:

---------------------------------------------------------- Updated -----------------------------------------------------------
To display the URL only if the name is not blank you can use the below code:
HTML:
<template>
    <template if:true={name}>
        <lightning-formatted-url value={url} label={name}></lightning-formatted-url>
    </template>
</template>

JS:
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class UrlName extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
    nameField;
    recordPageUrl;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: ['$objectApiName.Name'] })
    wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.nameField = getFieldValue(data, this.objectApiName + '.Name');
            // Only generate the URL if the name field is not empty
            if (this.nameField) {
                this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
                    type: 'standard__recordPage',
                    attributes: {
                        recordId: this.recordId,
                        actionName: 'view',
                    },
                }).then(url => {
                    this.recordPageUrl = url;
                });
            }
        } else if (error) {
            // Handle the error appropriately
            console.error('Error retrieving record:', error);
        }
    }

    get name() {
        return this.nameField;
    }

    get url() {
        return this.recordPageUrl;
    }
}


That worked perfectly. One more question (my javascript knowledge is poor). In connectedcallback, where you are generating url, how do we put the condition if name is blank, this.recordPageUrl = ''. Basically, if there is no value in the Name field, i dont want hyperlink to appear by itself. I want whole component to be empty if Name field is empty (or not retrieved properly)

@user2957592, I have added an updated code in the answer.
